# Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable<any> | null | undefined'. in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

learning angular and typescript for the first time and cannot understand why i am getting this error and how to fix it

i am trying to display historical weather data for specific day in a table using ngFor

i am using PrimeNG components

```
<div class="card" *ngIf="myWeather">
  <h5>London Historical Weather Data 12.05.2005</h5>
  <p-table [scrollable]="true" scrollHeight="400px" [tableStyle]="{'min-width': '50rem'}">
      <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <tr>
              <th>Time</th>
              <th>Temperature</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Air Pressure</th>
              <th>Humidity</th>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template pTemplate="body" *ngFor="let weather of myWeather" >    // error is here
          <tr>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
          </tr>
      </ng-template>
  </p-table>
</div>
```

weather.service.ts

```
  getWeatherData(): Observable<Weather> {
    return this.http.get<Weather>(
      'https://archive-api.open-meteo.com/v1/era5?latitude=51.51&longitude=-0.13&start_date=2005-08-25&end_date=2005-08-25&hourly=temperature_2m,relativehumidity_2m,dewpoint_2m,apparent_temperature,surface_pressure,precipitation,windspeed_10m&timezone=Europe%2FLondon',
      {
        params: new HttpParams(),
      }
    );
  }
}
```

that api returns object
component that its being used in

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-weather',
  templateUrl: './weather.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./weather.component.css'],
})
export class WeatherComponent implements OnInit {
  myWeather!: Weather;
  constructor(private weatherService: WeatherService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.weatherService.getWeatherData().subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response);
      this.myWeather = response;
    });
  }
}
```

Type 'Weather' is not assignable to type 'NgIterable | null | undefined'.ngtsc(2322)
weather.component.ts(5, 11): Error occurs in the template of component WeatherComponent.

i have tried

```
myWeather?: Weather[]
```

didnt work

this is the model which i formatted from the api json

```
export interface Weather {
  latitude: number;
  longitude: number;
  generationtime_ms: number;
  utc_offset_seconds: number;
  timezone: string;
  timezone_abbreviation: string;
  elevation: number;
  hourly_units: HourlyUnits;
  hourly: Hourly;
}

export interface HourlyUnits {
  time: string;
  temperature_2m: string;
  relativehumidity_2m: string;
  dewpoint_2m: string;
  apparent_temperature: string;
  surface_pressure: string;
  precipitation: string;
  windspeed_10m: string;
}

export interface Hourly {
  time: string[];
  temperature_2m: number[];
  relativehumidity_2m: number[];
  dewpoint_2m: number[];
  apparent_temperature: number[];
  surface_pressure: number[];
  precipitation: number[];
  windspeed_10m: number[];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message is pretty clear I think. `*ngFor` is iterating over an array (or any iterable). Since `myWeather` is an object, and not an iterable, the error is thrown.

You should decide on what exactly you want to iterate over. The only array you have are included in the type `Hourly`, so I assume you want to iterate over these.

You could use `*ngFor="let time of myWeather.hourly.time"` to do this.

Please be aware that typescript will not ensure that your actual API response matches your defined type of myWeather during runtime. You have to manually check that your defined type matches the actual API response.